# R - split and merge paired dataset

Tags: r, merge, split

I would like to split and then merge a paired dataset.

My data look like this :

```
  idno Q2   variable time    value
1  561 56 tuconjoint    1     fait
2  562 56 tuconjoint    1     fait
3  561 56 tuconjoint    2     fait
4  562 56 tuconjoint    2     fait
5  561 56       tutv    1 non fait
6  562 56       tutv    1 non fait
7  561 56       tutv    2 non fait
8  562 56       tutv    2 non fait
```

So it is made of two individuals (`idno`) belonging to one pair (`Q2`) observed during two episodes (`time`) for two different variables (`tuconjoint` and `tutv`).

What I am trying to do is to **split** and then **merge** the two `variables`.

I found the first part :

```
split(dtAct, dtAct$variable)
```

Which gives me two lists.

I tried this and it seems to work but does not give me a smooth output :

```
split(dtAct, dtAct$variable) %>% as.data.frame()
```

The **output** I want is something like

```
     idno  Q2 time  variableA    valueA  variableB  valueB 
1    561  56   1    tuconjoint    fait    tutv      non fait
2    562  56   1    tuconjoint    fait    tutv      non fait
3    561  56   2    tuconjoint    fait    tutv      non fait
4    562  56   2    tuconjoint    fait    tutv      non fait
```

Any clue ?

```
dtAct = structure(list(idno = c(561, 562, 561, 562, 561, 562, 561, 562
), Q2 = c(56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("tuconjoint_1", "tuconjoint_2", 
"tutv_1", "tutv_2"), class = "factor"), value = c("fait", "fait", 
"fait", "fait", "non fait", "non fait", "non fait", "non fait"
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .Names = c("idno", "Q2", "variable", 
"value"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the split list

```
dtList <- split(dtAct, dtAct$variable)
```

you can refer to the objects of the list as

```
dtList$tuconjoint
dtList$tutv
```

so you can merge the two data frames togheter

```
dtRes <- merge(dtList$tuconjoint, dtList$tutv, by=c('idno','Q2','time'),
           suffixes = c('A','B'))
```

and the result will be

```
     idno Q2    time  variableA    valueA    variableB   valueB
  1  561  56    1     tuconjoint   fait      tutv        non fait
  2  561  56    2     tuconjoint   fait      tutv        non fait
  3  562  56    1     tuconjoint   fait      tutv        non fait
  4  562  56    2     tuconjoint   fait      tutv        non fait
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
library(tidyr)
dt1 <- separate(dtAct, variable, into=c('var', 'time')) 
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., 
           by = c('idno', 'Q2', 'time')), split(dt1, dt1$var))
```